# Link with custom function instead of crt one

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, crt

I'm working on an application which defines it's own printf() to get around differences between the different CRTs out there or because some other platforms don't have it.

When building the application with gcc this automatically seems to work and the custom printf is used instead of libc's one; if I understand it correctly this is because of the order in which object files/libraries appear in the link command or maybe because object files are always searched before CRT libs, correct?

I'd like to do the same using msvc. Just building the project gives the expected 'LNK2005: _printf already defined in printf.obj' because printf is also in msvcrtd.lib. Fair enough. I know about /NODEFAULTLIB but that excludes everything resulting in unresolved references for everything but printf. I scanned through the other linker settings but couldn't find anything which allows this (apart from /FORCE maybe, but the 'might produce an invalid executable' comment doesn't make it sound like a good idea). Also nothing in the module definition file docs; the latter got me thinking it might be possible to create a stub library which has all exports from msvcrt.lib except printf but that seems a brittle solution even if it works.

In the end the question is simple: how do I tell msvc's linker it should skip msvcrt's printf definition and use the one from my printf.obj instead. Basically /NODEFAULTFUNCTION:printf or so. Just an answer for one single executable is ok, though I'd also be interested to know if and how it can be done when building a dll instead where the custom printf is exported: how to tell the linker it should use the export from my .lib instead of msvcrt.lib?

*edit* simplest repo I could find: create a file main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("Hello");
  return 0;
}
```

and a file printf.c:

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  write(1, "ok\n", 3);
  return 3;
}
```

For VS2013 (though the other versions might work as well): create a new empty C++ project and add both files then build. (For gcc: just `gcc main.c printf.c` and the resulting a.out prints 'ok')

The culptrit for VS is #include : without that it works ok but I have yet to find out if the [original code](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/) allows getting rid of it in some way. But even if it does I'd still want to know if this can be solved at the link level.

Comment: You could give your function another name, say `myprintf` and put `#define printf myprintf` after your `#include` statements.

Comment: Works fine when I try it, albeit that VS2015 requires `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` to prevent it from being inlined.  Add the /VERBOSE linker option so you can see how it got pulled in.  And mention your VS version.  And show repro code.

Comment: ...and my suggestion means you won't have to struggle with the linker and duplicate function names on every platform you visit.

Comment: @WeatherVane ...but its is hard to manage with complex project with tens of compilation units, prebuld libs and so on.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's indeed an alternative though it basically comes down to LPs's comment.

Comment: Please, don't use acronyms when posting a problem, what the hell is a CRT?  It you refer to a Cathode Ray Tube, you're completely wrong... all the CRTs show the output of `printf(3)` exactly the same, as printf has been written to do exactly that.  A Cathode Ray Tube is only a component of a normally much more complex device called a display, and by the way, they are rarely used today (mainly because their weight, size and geometric nonlinearity)  Printf allows you even to print output to a printer, and it does exactly the same as on a CRT. Don't use fashion words if you want your q answered.

Comment: @LuisColorado fashion words like *q* :] ? Serisously, the title mentions linking, functions, and crt, and this is a programmer's Q&A site, and there even is a crt tag which I used in the question together with the c tag. Should there still be any doubts left about whether we're talking about some vacuum tube or something else: the tag is there to be hovered over or clicked on. But anyway, it seems unlikely answers from visitors who didn't make that link in the first place would be interesting or to the point.

Comment: well, now it's clarified that you didn't mean a cathode ray tube, which was common some time ago to make the computer screens, also related with computing science.  I had not complaint if I should not understand that, instead of C Run Time (which is what I think now you mean)  And this is the reason for asking (and not me only) not to use acronyms (or at least, use them once in their expanded form)

Comment: It's not me who is planning to rewrite the `printf(3)` function as some kind of scholar exercise.  I'm full of rewriting standard runtime (wihtout acronyms) functions to fit in some embedded or specific application.  It's precisely the purpose of standard runtime functions to be there to avoid rewriting them when you switch between runtimes (again without acronym)  Believe me or not, I've asked my question with the purpose of clarifying things, not to initiate a flame discussion.

Comment: *as some kind of scholar exercise* I don't know how you inferred that from the question but it makes no sense: the rewrite is part of the Micropython project (see link in question) which you can call a number of things, but *scholar exercise* really isn't one of them